# Simulating a controlled dynamical system

Tags: matlab, control-theory, simulation, octave

I am try to simulate a controlled dynamical system of the form

$$\dot{x}=f(x,\phi(x)),$$

where $\phi$ is the controller. To do so, I am using Octave (an open source version of Matlab).

My commands lines are

out = lsode("cl_system",IC(1),time);

where lsode is the solver function, cl_system is the function f, IC the initial condition, and time is the vector for time simulation.

the cl_system was written as follows

function out = cl_system(x,t)

u     = controller(x);

q_dot = fp(x,u);

out = q_dot;

endfunction.

Now, I would like to plot the vector u. In other words, I want to see the evolution of the controller in time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract your state $x$ at the end of the simulation (out variable in your code) and compute $\phi(x)$, which is your control input.